# How to pass a array from node to .js file (pugJs)

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js, pug

I am trying to render a chart (using `ChartJS`) as express response. The data points for the chart are stored in node as array. I have to pass it on to the chartJS function.

For that I'm currently using express's `res.render()` method. I have managed to pass the values to `.pug` file. Now i have to move the data points from `.pug` file to the `.js` file/ChartJS function.

How do i accomplish this? is this is the correct approach?

The end result I expect is that the array values stored in `node` has to be reflected on the `.js` file which has the ChartJS function.

I will be thankful for your help/advice of any kind.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) and a stringify to turn your pug variable into a client-side browser variable:

```
var arrayForChart = !{JSON.stringify(arrayInPug)};
```

If the variable in express/pug is `['a', 'b', 'c']` then this will output:

```
var arrayForChart = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Without the stringify you'll get something like this which will just throw an error in the browser as it's not valid JavaScript:

```
var arrayForChart = [Object object];
```