# Alert in Pug(Jade) after retrieving a value from the node server

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to implement an alert when the page loads under an expecific circunstance ,retrieving the value from an Node server when the user or passwowrd are wrong.
But it just doesnt do anything. I had tested it and yes, ErrorCon(the variable i get from my Node server) get its expected value when the circunstance appear so the node part shouldnt be the problem
This is the code i am trying to apply, right in the body:

```
 script.
  (function (){
    function init(){
      var Errors=ErrorCon;
      if (Errors==1){
        alert("Wrong password");
      }
    }
  window.addEventListener?
  window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
  window.attachEvent('onload',init);
  })();
```

The same structure works on a different page yet here it just doesnt do anything.
Help

Comment: How are you passing the value from node to the client?

Comment: res.render('login',{ErrorCon:ErrorConfirmation}); Where ErrorConfirmationhas the value 1 after I verified that tehre was an error, and login is the name of the pug file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a array from node to .js file (pugJs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528213/how-to-pass-a-array-from-node-to-js-file-pugjs)